# SQL Server : use SELECT convert instead of SELECT format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I've been given this statement:

```
Select Format((
    Select Max([Date])
    from BusinessDaysCalendar
    where [date] in (
         Select top 1 [date]
         from BusinessDaysCalendar
         where date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )
),'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US') [retval]
```

which returns the date in this format `08/22/2014`

I want to use `Select CONVERT` instead to get the date formatted as `Aug 22, 2014`. I know how to use this statement to get what I need

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107)
```

I'm just having a hard time integrating it with the first statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted your query into something which is more readable--by which, I mean that it's easier to determine what's part of a given statement, such as where an argument is for the Convert function, and which lines are part of each subquery.

I also included a 2nd version which I think is accomplishing what you want, but is a little simpler because it skips 1 subquery level.  My understanding is that you are trying to return a single row for the lowest date following the current date.  The problem with your most inner subquery is that without an Order By, there is no guaranty that the row returned will be the lowest value.  The Top 1 simply tells it to return the 1st row it comes across, and it's possible this isn't the lowest of the values meeting your criteria.

```
    Select convert(varchar(12)
                    ,( --this is the 2nd argument for the 'convert' function
                       select (
                                Select Max([Date]) --determine the Max (Date) **It looks like you're trying to get the first value after today, and ensure you're only returning 1 row
                                from BusinessDaysCalendar 
                                where [date] 
                                        in (--select the 1st date ** note: since this subquery is only returning a single row, you can use "=" instead of "in"
                                            Select top 1 [date] 
                                            from BusinessDaysCalendar 
                                            where date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                                )
                        )
                    ,107 --the 3rd argument for 'convert'
    ) [retval]

    Select convert(varchar(12)
                    ,( --this is the 2nd argument for the 'convert' function
                       select (
                                Select min([Date]) --determine the Max (Date) **It looks like you're trying to get the first value after today, and ensure you're only returning 1 row
                                    from BusinessDaysCalendar 
                                    where date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                )
                        )
                    ,107 --the 3rd argument for 'convert'
    ) [retval]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to replace "GETDATE()" with the first statement.  So:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),
(Select 
    Max([Date]) 
from BusinessDaysCalendar 
where [date] in 
   (Select 
        top 1 [date] 
    from BusinessDaysCalendar 
    where date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
),107)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, but as I was working on it, i came across the solution:

```
Select convert(varchar(12),(
select (
Select Max([Date]) 
from BusinessDaysCalendar 
where [date] in (
Select top 1 [date] 
from BusinessDaysCalendar 
where date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))),107) [retval]
```

This gave me the value Aug 22, 2014 I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You realize you have an extra SELECT statement in there that's not necessary, right?